# Different onboarding experiences for different personas?

Tags: usability, web-app, onboarding

I want to design the onboarding experience of a project management platform that is similar to Asana or Monday for example. I want to leave an optional guide for users on how to start creating certain items on the platform like a new task, appointment, etc.

I can't help but notice that a completely new user can easily play around with all the features without worrying about breaking things. However, users who will join organizations later that already have data being used might be intimidated to play around with features fearing the possibility of breaking things.

I'm not even sure if I should provide them with a guide that encourages them to start creating new items everywhere or not like the completely new users.

Is it better to create 2 different onboarding experiences? or should I just create a single onboarding experience that doesn't encourage users to start creating new items everywhere?
I also thought about creating something like a playground where users can go and just mess with the features without consequences, but I fear this might be too much for something that should be simpler than that.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Creating 2 on-boarding experiences will add complexity.

When I have gone though an boarding, similar to what you have described, the entire environment is in a playground (new and empty). Once the user has 'graduated' from the tutorial, they are then placed inside their production environment with the shared files present. In some cases the user can just skip the tutorial and be placed directly into the production environment.

If you want to incorporate the on boarding directly into the production environment, you can have the user go through the process of performing all the operations, and then have them delete or remove those objects as a last step, while locking down the actions they can perform at each step to ensure they don't affect the production files.

Comment: Sandbox versions are great for learning during a tutorial as long as they are populated in a realistic way.

Comment: Thanks. I dunno why I haven't thought of that before even though I spent so much of my youth playing video games and so many of them used that exact method you're describing :D